# Quartz Grails plugin

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm building an application using `Grails 3.3.11` and [Quartz Grails plugin 2.0.13](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz), there were some old jobs I migrated them to my new application and they were working fine previously, however now I'm getting the below error when I'm trying to run them manually from `Quartz monitor` page, also getting the same error when after creating a new job and try to run it manually. Any Idea what may be causing this error and how to solve it?

```
    2020-09-07 17:12:29.308 ERROR --- [SchedulerThread] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger : An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'GRAILS_JOBS.utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob'

org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob]!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.b

    eans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at 

    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory.createJobInstance(GrailsJobFactory.java:48)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzMonitorJobFactory.super$3$createJobInstance(QuartzMonitorJobFactory.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1433)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzMonitorJobFactory.createJobInstance(QuartzMonitorJobFactory.groovy:24)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob]!
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1433)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static grails.web.api.WebAttributes.$init$() is applicable for argument types: (utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob) values: [utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob@27cf1bcc]
    Possible solutions: wait(), find(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), println(), wait(long)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1518)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:921)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:181)
        at grails.web.api.WebAttributes$Trait$Helper.$static_methodMissing(WebAttributes.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1433)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1516)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob.<init>(EveryEndOfDayJob.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:118)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Here is my sample job:

```
class EveryEndOfDayJob {
    //def utilsService
    static triggers = {
        cron name: "daily", cronExpression: "0 0 1 * * ?" 
    }

    def execute() {
      
println("Job is running")

    }
}
```

Comment: Have jobs been working fine after migration or before a migration? Have you tried to downgrade the plugin?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc they were working fine before the migration , I reviewed  the plugin documentation they are recommending  the version I'm using for Grails 3 http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/latest/

Answer (score 0):

After downloading Grails 3.3.13 and creating brand new project, you can add plugin quartz 2.0.13 and everything is working as expected: https://github.com/majkelo/stackoverflow-quartz-issue

[image]

If I were you, I'd focus on the exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob]!

especially check: `Error creating bean with name 'utradeorders.EveryEndOfDayJob'`

have you put this job in the proper place / subfolder? what will happen if you move it out of `utradeorders` subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

When I was reviewing the `build.gradle` I found it was written `compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'` I changed it to `runtime` and everything worked as expected.